# String replace regex invalid quantifier in js/GAS

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Based on https://www.plivo.com/blog/Send-templatized-SMS-from-a-Google-spreadsheet-using-Plivo-SMS-API/ I have the following code:

```
function createMessage(){
  data = {
    "SOURCE" : "+1234567890",
    "DESTINATION" : "+2345678901",
    "FIRST_NAME" : "Jane",
    "LAST_NAME" : "Doe",
    "COUPON" : "DUMMY20",
    "STORE" : "PLIVO",
    "DISCOUNT" : "20",
  }

  template_data = "Hi   , your coupon code for discount of % purchase at  is "
  Logger.log(data);

  for (var key in data) {
    Logger.log(key);

    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      template_data = template_data.replace(new RegExp('+key+', 'gi'),data[key]); // error here
    }
  }
  Logger.log(template_data);
  return template_data;
}
```

When I run `createMessage` I get :

```
SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier +. (line 57, file "Code")
```

From a previous question and if I understand correctly the loop goes through each key, value pair looking for all matches of the key (g) in a case insensitive fashion (i).

I don't understand the pattern '+key+' This causes the error and my attempts to test patterns like '+SOURCE+' also give the same error, although the seem to work while testing at https://regex101.com/r/CF967t/2 .

Can someone give me an explanation of the problem

Comment: It looks like the examples posted in the link you shared are incorrect. Another example of a mistake is that their 'template_data' is missing some of the tokens which they expect to replace

Comment: Thanks @John I wondered about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sign + usually is a repetition operator, and causes the preceding token to repeat one or more times key+ would be expressed as keykey*

You have pass only *key*

```
template_data = template_data.replace(new RegExp(key, 'gi'),data[key]);
```